# avoid SettingWithCopyWarning when using a function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, warnings, pandas-settingwithcopy-warning

I have DataFrame and I need to derivate a new column based on the value of an existing column.

```
class SomeClass:
  def reduce(self, x):
    if x < 1:
        return x ** 2
    return np.sqrt(x)    


  def penalize_performance(self, df):
    df['sqrt'] = df.apply(lambda x : self.reduce(x.perf), axis=1)
    return df
```

The result is correct but I get the **SettingWithCopyWarning** warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

How to I fix the syntax, to avoid the issue ?

Comment: The problem is on the df you pass to your function not your class itself. How do you define this dataframe? for example, is it a sub-part of a bigger dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way i found to avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`, (which basically warns you to check your results, as the method chaining, might not work as intended, meaning, it could update only a subset of your DataFrame" **copy of the original DatFrame"** instead of your original DataFrame)

is to use `.loc[]`

```
class SomeClass:
  def reduce(self, x):
    if x < 1:
        return x ** 2
    return np.sqrt(x)    


  def penalize_performance(self, df):
    df.loc[:, 'sqrt'] = df.apply(lambda x : self.reduce(x.perf), axis=1) #Edited line using .loc[] to update a dataframe.
    return df
```